# Mobile menu not working

Tags: joomla-3.4, javascript, css, cache, mobile-web-design

I have got caching turned on for this website:

http://storm.agency/

But I am not caching the nav module, also cleared any cache but the mobile menu is not dropping down when viewing the site on a mobile device.

I've tried debugging it but nothing obvious as to why it's not working

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was an error with the styling.

```
body div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This was the culprit!